# Move framework & native runtime files into a sub-folder

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

asp.net core 2.2 publish generating lots off DLL in output directory(bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish).
How I can move it to some other folder (bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\lib) & reference it?

Answer (score -1):

Your question doesn't really make sense, but I imagine you're looking for a way to include a library from one solution in another. This is not the way to do that.

Instead, package your project as a NuGet. Then, you can reference the NuGet package in your other solution's projects. Some people are confused and think creating NuGet packages means having to make them public on the main NuGet repository. While you can of course do that, it's not required. You have a private repo, either through a third-party or deploy your own, or you can simply use a filesystem path or network location as a "repo".

In any case, creating a NuGet package is simple. You simply edit your project properties, go to the "Package" tab, and enable NuGet package creation. Fill in the relevant details about your package on that screen, and you're off to the races. Whenever you build or publish your project, you'll get a NuGet package created in the same directory. Then, just push that to your NuGet repo, or if it's a filesystem path or network location, copy it there.